Multer file upload problem with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" Error"
I've tried so many time to upload file using multer but I always get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I uploaded file previously with the same code. Can anyone tell me why?
multer.middleware.js:
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, 'public');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        console.log(ext);
        return cb(null, Date.now()+ext);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg'  || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

export {upload};

controller.js:
import {Employee} from './employee.model.js';
import { uploadCloudinary } from './cloudinary.js';

//Add employee
const addEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, phone, dob } = req.body;
    if ([name, email, phone, dob].some(field => field?.trim() === '')) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' });
    }

    const isExist = await Employee.findOne({ $or:[{email},{phone}] });
    if(isExist) {
        console.log("User with email or phone already exist! Try new one..");
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'User with email or phone already exist! Try new one..' });
}
    const imagePath = req.files?.avatar[0]?.path;
    if (!imagePath) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Avatar is required and path!' });

    const avatar = await uploadCloudinary(imagePath);
    if (!avatar) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Avatar is required!' });

    const employee = await Employee.create({
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        dob,
        avatar: avatar?.url || '',
    });

};

export default { addEmployee};

router.js:
import { Router } from "express";
import controller from "./employee.controller.js";
import {upload} from './multe.middileware.js'

const router = Router();
router.route("/add").post( 
    upload.fields([{
        name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1,
    }]) ,controller.addEmployee);

export default router;

NB: I try to fix it by changing
const imagePath = req.files?.avatar[0]?.path;

to
const imagePath = req.files?.avatar?.path;

In this case, the TypeError is gone but file isn't uploaded. I get a message "Avatar path is required".
My question is since the code ran properly earlier, why is it causing an error now?

how are you making the request

using postman: at  origin - http://localhost:8000/employee/add
and I have an app.js file where I have import router component. And I use import employee from './employee.route.js'; app.use("/employee", employee);

the error suggests that the file is not processed, so try debugging in that direction, check if there is some other middleware in between

Finally, I got the solution. This problem is gone by, degrade the  multer. I remove multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1 version and install multer^1.4.3.
